# what does expression %r |something | mean in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm a ruby beginner, when I read other guy's ruby code, I found something like "%r |/usr/doc/readme.txt|"  as an array's elements. But I don't understand what it is. Can anyone please explain this a little bit and point me to some ruby documents which talk about such thing?

Answer (score 0):

It is used for interpolated regular expressions